# Why cucumber+selenium test giving error when running as run as junit test case?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have created a test case with `cucumber` and `selenium` when i am running the command `mvn clean install` the test case executed without error and passed successfully but the same test case when i am running with spring tool suite with option run as junit test case it was giving error.

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:48)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okies Got the answer classes are not in the class path

**after mvn eclipse:eclipse**

it worked.